# How to install/change locale on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, localization

I've written a web application for which the user interface is in Dutch. I use the system's date and time routines to format date strings in the application. However, the date strings that the system formats are in English but I want them in Dutch, so I need to set the system's locale. How do I do that on Debian? I tried setting `LC_ALL=nl_NL` but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
$ date
Sat Aug 15 14:31:31 UTC 2009
$ LC_ALL=nl_NL date
Sat Aug 15 14:31:36 UTC 2009
```

I remember that setting LC_ALL on my Ubuntu desktop system works fine. Do I need to install extra packages to make this work, or am I doing it entirely wrong?

Comment: is there a way to do this automatically based on the assigned ip address of the server?

Comment: [Setting Debian Locale the standard way](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard): `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/locale` and set the contents to:

```
LANG="nl_NL.UTF-8"
```

You can check which locales you currently have generated using:

```
locale -a
```

You can generate more by editing `/etc/locale.gen` and uncommenting the lines for the locales that you want to enable. Then you can generate them by running the command:

```
locale-gen
```

You can find a list of supported locales in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`

There is more information available on the [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Locale).

Comment: /var/lib/belocs/list doesn't exist.  You need to edit /etc/locale.gen or run dpkg-reconfigure locales instead.

Comment: +1 this answer for describing locale-gen, but as per the previous comment, there's no such file as /var/lib/belocs/list on my system

Comment: It took me 5 hours to find this answer, which ended up being perfect.
Moreover, it allows to make aliases: en_US UTF-8 and it_IT UFT-8 allowed me to have my locales in UTF-8 by default, which is great if you have PHP code that depends on locales

Comment: Is there a command or package which can edit and set the contents of /etc/default/locale ?

Comment: See answer below from Czar. 
You can do it like: sed -i 's/^# *\(en_US.UTF-8\)/\1/' /etc/locale.gen

Comment: `$ locale-gen: command not found` even when doing `$ sudo apt install locales` so going for `$ dpkg-reconfigure locales` is the only one thing working

Answer (score 94):

You may need to install the `locales` package.  This will ask you which locales to generate.  If it's already installed, then `dpkg-reconfigure locales` will let you generate more locales.

Comment: That only generates locales, not set the system default.

Comment: NO, the final question of dpkg-reconfigure locales is to select the default locale.

Comment: I had to run it with `sudo` as in `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.

Comment: If it's a server accessed through ssh [the Debian wiki page on locales](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Standard) recommends leaving leave the default locale set to `NONE`.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed: get all locales installed in just a few keystrokes. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PaulRougieux I also noticed the recommendation of setting it to `None` when using **ssh** but I wonder why?! I use `en_US.UTF-8` as system default and haven't experienced any issues with that...

Answer (score 56):

Answers here are incomplete as with most elsewhere. After piecing together information from a few places, what worked for me was to (1) make sure the locale I wanted was available (generate it if it wasn't) then (2) set locale related environment variables to desired locale.

In my case I needed `en_US.UTF-8` programmatically (i.e. non-interactively) installed in a docker container. The ff accomplished what I need but it should work just fine in an interactive shell.

```
apt-get update

# Install locales package
apt-get install -y locales

# Uncomment en_US.UTF-8 for inclusion in generation
sed -i 's/^# *\(en_US.UTF-8\)/\1/' /etc/locale.gen

# Generate locale
locale-gen

# Export env vars
echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bashrc
```

On the same shell, you will need to do `source ~/.bashrc` for the env vars to take effect immediately. You can check that locale has been configured correctly by invoking `locale`.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

There were a lot of Q&A entries regarding this subject but only a few were actually helpful. Credit where credit is due:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247019/21289
- https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment

Comment: This worked for us when needing a locale set for a dotnet application running in the official Microsoft images.

Comment: This worked for me when setting up a Docker container. However after doing `locale-gen`, instead of adding env vars to the `~/.bashrc`, I did `update-locale LANG=en_US.utf8` as `root` user to set system-wide locale to new users.

Comment: Thanks, and worth to mention many non us or default encodings for a given language or not written in a full form, but just like the abbreviations for that language-country without the encoding suffix , eg "sk_SK" instead of "sk_SK.ISO-8859-2". And if it has a suffix for a non default encoding, it has to contain dashes like "ISO-8859-2" unlike provided by the output of command "ISO88592"

Answer (score 12):

None of these answers worked for me, on an LXC container installed with:

```
lxc-create -n sse-master -t download -n sse-master -- \
    -d debian -r jessie --arch i386
```

I always got the following output from `locale-gen`, i.e. not generating any locales (none listed):

```
$ sudo locale-gen
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
```

Running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and selecting some locales did not update `/etc/locale.gen` as I expected it to.

However, when I modified that file manually and uncommented the locales that I wanted, then `locale-gen` started working properly:

```
$ sudo locale-gen
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

I was also able to generate locales manually like this:

```
sudo localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
sudo localedef -i en_GB -f UTF-8 en_GB.UTF-8
```

But this was not a permanent solution: I found that running `locale-gen` without the `--keep-existing` option will delete all such manually-generated locales, i.e. every locale not listed (and uncommented) in `/etc/locale.gen`.

Answer (score 5):

For those who, like me, on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, have, somehow, no `/etc/locale.gen` file, you can add a new locale in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` and then run :

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

You can also add the french (for example) locale this way (instead of editing `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`) :

`sudo locale-gen fr_FR fr_FR.UTF-8`

to add and generate the `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8` codesets of the `fr_FR` locale and finally type :

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

to finish the job

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that `supported.d/local` file, I found the unnecessary defines there. Took me way too long to find :/

Answer (score 4):

For a web application, it might be better to use **setlocale**() *inside* the program, rather than requiring that the system default locale be set appropriately outside. Less loose ends that way.

Comment: If the system doesn't have required locale, than `setlocale` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Some of the commands below require root privileges, consider the use of `sudo`.

#### Basic info

According to [`man locale-gen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/locale-gen.8.html), locales are set in several files.

> `/etc/locale.gen`
>
> The main configuration file, which has a simple format: every line that is not empty  and does not begin with a # is treated as a locale definition that is to be built.
>
> `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/`
>
> A  directory  containing  locale.gen  snippets provided by language-pack packages.  Do not edit these manually, they will be overwritten on package upgrades.

Comprehensive details on locales at the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale).

#### Checking locales and the locale

To check the (already) generated locales, run any of the following commands (with minor output differences).

```sh
locale -a
localedef --list-archive
localectl list-locales
```

To check the currently used locale, run any of the following commands (with minor output differences).

```sh
locale
localectl
```

#### Setting and generating (new) locales

Locales are typically set by uncommenting lines in `/etc/locale.gen`, after which running `locale-gen` is required.

```sh
nano /etc/locale.gen # uncomment desired lines (locales)
locale-gen
```

This will generate locales files for each uncommented line in `/etc/locale.gen` (and under `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/`), whether they were previously generated or not.

Alternatively, the command

```sh
locale-gen <locale>
```

will uncomment the corresponding line in `locale-gen` while generating the desired locale and only this one.

#### Removing locales

To remove locales in `/etc/locale.gen`, simply comment the desired lines and regenerate the locales using `locale-gen`. The command `locale-gen --purge <locale>` doesn't do what the modifier suggests.

To remove locales under `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/` is trickier. Since any file `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/<code>` depends on the package `language-pack-<code>-base`, any change on the former will be restored when the latter is updated.

**Workaround.** To prevent changes under `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/`, set files in it with the ["immutable (i)" attribute](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/chattr.1.html). So instead of removing files, empty them. For instance:

```sh
cd /var/lib/locales/supported.d/
rm <code> && touch <code> # <code> has been emptied
lsattr <code>    # regular attributes
chattr +i <code> # adding (+) immutable
lsattr <code>    # checking attributes
```

#### Setting the locale

Setting and generating locales does not set the system locale. Any of the following commands achieves this.

```sh
echo LANG=<code> | sudo tee /etc/locale.conf # reboot (might be ignored in Ubuntu)
localectl set-locale LANG=<code>
```

Comment: This comes from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1281631/762841).

Comment: It is not attribution, post is mine as well.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I didn't visit the link.

Answer (score 1):

But first you need to have needed language pack installed. On my German based VPS there was no english language pack pre-installed. So first you check that you have it installed:

```
aptitude install language-pack-en
```