# reset locale in debian under Squeeze

Tags: debian-squeeze, localization

I have problems with locale in debian. I tried many thing but it doesn't anything for me :

```
locale -a

locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

I try to set en_US.utf8 without success with this :

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales -plow
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

After reboot, i try to use a perl script :

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Here is my /etc/default/locale config file :

```
cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
```

Any idea to solve this (stupid) problem ?

Thanks

Comment: may be duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/54591/how-to-install-change-locale-on-debian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that

```
apt-get install locales-all
```

solved my problem

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install locales --reinstall
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: it didn't workded too : apt-get install locales --reinstall
(...)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4761 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 33, in <module>
    from ALChacks import *
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/ALChacks.py", line 32, in <module>
    sys.stderr.write(_("Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!\n"))
NameError: name '_' is not defined
Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Install the missing `en_US` locale by running:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

then:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: it didn't worked for me : perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = "en_US",
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

Comment: Show us the output of the first command `sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8`?

Comment: locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.